# How to add several fields in a module that belong to two tables in the same form or other - Prestashop 1.7

Tags: module, prestashop, addition

I have followed the steps of a tutorial to create a module to edit invoices specifically this:
https://blog.floriancourgey.com/2018/04/edit-your-invoices-in-prestashop

But the module only allows updating the information of the fields that appear in a single table.

The thing is, I need to add a new field that belongs to another table and is saved in both tables.
The table that stores the module information is ps_order_invoice and the table that I also want to save, a single invoice_number field, is ps_orders.

```
  class AdminCustomInvoicesController extends ModuleAdminController {
  public function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
$this->bootstrap = true; // use Bootstrap CSS
$this->table = 'order_invoice'; // SQL table name, will be prefixed with _DB_PREFIX_
$this->identifier = 'id_order_invoice'; // SQL column to be used as primary key
$this->className = 'OrderInvoice'; // PHP class name
$this->allow_export = true; // allow export in CSV, XLS..
$this->_orderBy = 'date_add'; // default SQL ORDER BY
$this->page_header_toolbar_title = 'Invoices'; // toolbar title
$this->_select = 'concat(upper(c.lastname), " ", c.firstname) as customer';
$this->_join = '
  JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders o ON (o.id_order = a.id_orderes)
  JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'customer c ON (c.id_customer = o.id_customer)
';

$this->fields_list = [
  'id_order_invoice' => ['title' => $this->trans('ID', [], 'Admin.Global'),'class' => 'fixed-width-xs'],
  'number' => ['title' => $this->trans('Number', [], 'Admin.Global'),'class' => 'fixed-width-xs'],
 //I want add this new field(invoice_number) in another table ps_orders
  'invoice_number' => ['title' => $this->trans('Invoice Number', [], 'Admin.Global'),'class' => 'fixed-width-xs'],
  'date_add' => ['title' => $this->trans('Date', [], 'Admin.Global'), 'type'=>'datetime'],
  'customer' => ['title' => $this->trans('Customer', [], 'Admin.Global')],
  'total_products_wt' => ['title' => $this->trans('Total products', [], 'Admin.Global'),
    'align' => 'text-right',
    'type' => 'price',
  ],
  'total_shipping_tax_incl' => ['title' => $this->trans('Total shipping', [], 'Admin.Global'),
    'align' => 'text-right',
    'type' => 'price',
  ],
  'total_paid_tax_incl' => ['title' => $this->trans('Total paid', [], 'Admin.Global'),
    'align' => 'text-right',
    'type' => 'price',
  ],
];
```

I have also added in field_list

```
$this->fields_form = [
  'legend' => ['title' => $this->l('Custom Invoice'),'icon' => 'icon-list-ul'],
  'input' => [
    ['name' => 'date_add','type' => 'datetime','label' => 'Date add',],
    ['name'=>'number','type'=>'text','required' => true,'label' => 'Number',],
 //Here I add new field from ps_orders
    ['name'=>'invoice_number','type'=>'text','required' => true,'label' => 'Invoice number',],
    ['name'=>'note','type'=>'textarea','label' => 'Note',],
    ['name'=>'delivery_number','type'=>'text','label'=>'Delivery number'],
    ['name'=>'delivery_date','type'=>'datetime','label'=>'Delivery date'],
    ['name'=>'total_discount_tax_excl','type'=>'text','label'=>'Total amount of discounts (no tax)'],
    ['name'=>'total_discount_tax_incl','type'=>'text','label'=>'Total amount of discounts (with tax)'],
    ['name'=>'total_shipping_tax_excl','type'=>'text','label'=>'Total cost of shipping (no tax)'],
    ['name'=>'total_shipping_tax_incl','type'=>'text','label'=>'Total cost of shipping (with tax)'],
    ['name'=>'total_products','type'=>'text','label'=>'Total cost of products (no tax)'],
    ['name'=>'total_products_wt','type'=>'text','label'=>'Total cost of products (with tax)'],
    ['name'=>'total_wrapping_tax_excl','type'=>'text','label'=>'Total cost of wrapping (no tax)'],
    ['name'=>'total_wrapping_tax_incl','type'=>'text','label'=>'Total cost of wrapping (with tax)'],
    ['name'=>'total_paid_tax_excl','type'=>'text','label'=>'Total paid (no tax)'],
    ['name'=>'total_paid_tax_incl','type'=>'text','label'=>'Total paid (with tax)'],
    ['name'=>'shop_address','type'=>'textarea','label'=>'Shop address'],
  ],
  'submit' => ['title' => $this->trans('Save', [], 'Admin.Actions'),]
];
```

How can I add the invoice_number field to this module so that it updates in the table ps_orders when I put the data and at the same time the rest of the things that the module does?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

I have create one query in this place:
Db::getInstance()->execute('UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'orders` SET invoice_number = '.$invoice->number.' WHERE id_order = '.$invoice->id_order.'');